# Solving $f(n) = n \log(n)$ using this version of Master theorem.

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve this $T(n)= 2T(n/2) + n\log(n)$ using this version of master theorem in my lecture notes:
[image]

But I cannot be able to solve it. But if I use other version master theorem found on net, one example wiki's
[image]

I am able to solve this question using case 2. So which theorem is to use? And there are different case 2 solutions for different Master Theorem versions. Which is the best to apply? I am quite confused.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, if the second theorem is more detailed, then why not use that? There is no "one" Master Theorem, and instead of worrying about finding the right one it is always easier to derive the solution by hand.